# Консольный вывод с горизонтальными скролами

Tags: linux, консоль

### Проблема

- открываю лог `apache` (например командой `cat`) и на экране наблюдаю все перемешанное. Это происходит из за переноса строк что бы поместить все на одном экране

### Что нужно

- отключить перенос невлезающих строк

### Окружение

- ubuntu
- bash
- console (емулятор xterm)

### Что пробовал

- `... | less -RS` вроде все решает, но плохо работает, и не всегда можно использовать
- `stty columns 2000` должна бы увеличить виртуальный размер строки, но ничего не работает
- `xterm +aw` именно то что нужно, просто отключает перевод строки, но не получаеться подружить с gnome/xfce терминалом, любая параметризация приводит к ошибке `*** VTE ***: Failed to load terminal capabilities from '/etc/termcap'` (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=640940)

Answer (score 2):

можно воспользоваться программой *less*, передав ей опцию `-S` (`--chop-long-lines`). так:

```
$ cat file | less -S
```

или так:

```
$ less -S file
```

после этого стрелками управления курсором «вправо»/«влево» можно перемещать отображаемый текст по горизонтали.

---

кстати, этот режим можно включить/отключить прямо при работе программы *less*, введя два символа `-S` и нажав <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: способ хороший, но нельзя сделать так `tial -f file | less -S`, и наблюдаю что less не отображает цвета (догадываюсь что нужно настроить)

Comment: @duhon, 1. `$ tail -f file | less -S` — отлично работает. 2. цвет «делается» с помощью вставки спец-символов. за интерпретацию символов в программе *less* отвечает опция `-R`. естественно, «раскрашивающая» программа должна выдавать эти спец-символы. например: `$ grep --color=always строка файл | less -R`.

Comment: да согласен, незаметил что нужно перематывать вниз когда что то добавляеться. Но есть какаято пролема, когда доматываю до конца то less зависает, пока не убью процесс, ощущение что он пытаеться найти конец и виснет.

Comment: @duhon: можно обойтись без tail, в самом less если нажать `F` - будет режим аналогичный tail'у - т. е. автоматический вывод новых данных при их записи в файл. Отключается этот режим по `Ctrl-C`, сам less при этом не закрывается. Перематывать вручную, соответственно, необходимости нет.

Comment: в режиме слежение невожно подняться на пару строк выше. Если выключить слежение то less не закрываеться но как потом опять вернуться к слежению не перезапуская less.

Comment: @duhon, ещё раз нажмите `F`